# Subdomains not working after migration due to uppercase presence

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, subdomain, lets-encrypt

During migration we moved subdomains from our previous SSL provider to LetsEncrypt for SSL certificate change. Some of the subdomains had uppercases in them, but during certificate generation, in LEtsEncrypt the subdomain can be created only in lowercase.(We even tried to create subdomain names with uppercase, but it didn't work) After the migration, the subdomains that had uppercases in them arent working if we point the newly generated Letsencrypt certificates but they are working with perfectly with the previous provider. Does anyone know how to solve this problem or even better know any way to generate the certificate name with uppercases in them? 
Example 
The subdomain names are **Support.Example.com** but the certificate can only be generated for support.example.com

Answer (score 0):

DNS is case insensitive. So you wrongly define your hosts (presumably in apache) with upercase. Rename them to lower case and use Lets Encrypt certificates.